# BackboneJs Router

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, routes

so, Im trying to make an example app with backbone, but I can't make the router work, any ideas on what's wrong with this?, Thanks.
this is my router

```
var Workspace = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes:{
      "":"mainView",
      "event":"event"
    },
    initialize: function(){
      console.log('Hai');
      //view = new MainView();
      //this.render(view);
      //alert( this.routes[Backbone.history.getFragment()] );
    },
    mainView: function(){
      console.log('Load main view');
      view = new MainView();
      this.render(view);
    },
    event: function(){
      view = new EventView();
      this.render(view);
    },
    render: function(view){
      if(this.currentView){
        this.currentView.destroy();
      }
      view.render();
      this.currentView = view;
    }
  });
  var router = new Workspace();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ypuh8yqv/

the router gets Initialized cause I see the hai log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to start Backbone's History module. Add this line after you create the router instance:

```
Backbone.history.start();
```

If you want to use push state history (so there are no hashes in the url), you can enable push state:

```
Backbone.history.start({pushState: true})
```

For more, [see the Backbone History docs](http://backbonejs.org/#History-start).

Comment: Oh, it works, If I use it with pushsState it not work, gonna take a look to pushState, Thanks

Comment: @AngelRomeroHerrera Great; I'll be happy to answer any pushState questions. I'd appreciate if you could mark this as the answer. :)

Comment: I will, It just need 5 more minutes aha

Comment: :) Thanks! (I didn't realize there was a time limit.)